# Ionic 2: Items in list slow to respond to click

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building an Ionic 2 app that has a `<ion-list>` with `<ion-item>`s with (click) events. On loading the page with the `<ion-list>` it takes a few seconds before the `<ion-item>` click events become active and tappable. Tapping the items has no effect until a couple of seconds after the page has loaded.

I have only a few items in the list, and have tried with the virtualScroll list but to no effect.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: The cause can be multiple, can you provide a code snippet ?

Comment: I've figured out a fix. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured out a work around for this unresponsiveness. Instead of using an ion-item use a `<div>` tag with `tappable` and `ion-item` attributes set.

The code below shows the fix in place

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="news">
    <div tappable ion-item *virtualItem="let n" text-wrap (click)="openNews(n)">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-20>
          <img *ngIf="n.thumbnail" [src]="n.thumbnail">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-80 text-wrap>
          <h2>{{n.post_title}}</h2>
          <p [innerHTML]="n.post_excerpt"></p>
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: +1 for posting the solution, and also this issue might be raleted https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5838

Comment: tappable did the trick along with IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      pageTransition: 'md-transition'
    }),

Comment: Note: you don't have to use divs, you can still use ion-item as long as you add the `tappable` attribute.

Comment: I used same code but got this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'length' of null at VirtualScroll.readUpdate. Please tell how you initialised your news array. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750977/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-length-of-null-at-virtualscroll-readup