# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'length' of null at VirtualScroll.readUpdate

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I was using simple ion-list with ngFor to display items in a list in ionic 3 & was working fine. Then I used virtual scroll with ion-list & now I am getting following error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'length' of null at VirtualScroll.readUpdate**

Code snippet:

```
 <ion-list [virtualScroll]="anArray" approxItemHeight="50px">
        <div *virtualItem="let arrayItem">
    //other code

Array declaration: 
    public anArray: any[];

In constructor:
    this.anArray = [];

After network response:
    this.anArray = data.result;
```

Comment: You need to show the full code of that page.

Comment: did you try setting value in declaration itself?     `public anArray: any[]=[];`

Comment: Already tried. No luck.

Comment: can you just try to create a workaround (for debug purpose), set a boolean to true in your 'after network response' and set an `*ngIf="thatBoolean"` on your `<ion-list>` just to see if it's a problem with virtual scroll or with your list

Comment: Done it. This time no error but no item is displayed in list.

Comment: I saw that same issue is also reported here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10971 but no solution at all.

Comment: I think the solution can be found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840408/ionic-virtualscrool-cannot-read-property-length-off-null). Good luck!