# Ionic VirtualScroll Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: ionic3

I´m trying to use virtual scroll in Ionic 3 but it is not working.

I have this function on my provider:

```
getActiveAds(){
    return this.afDb.list<AngularFireList<any>>('/ads-active', ref => ref.orderByChild('adPlanPriority').startAt(1).endAt(3))
  }
```

On my list page, i have this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public adProvider: AdProvider) {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
    this.loading.present();

    this.ads = this.adProvider.getActiveAds().valueChanges()
    this.ads.subscribe((cat)=> {
      this.loading.dismiss()
    })
  }
```

and my list.html this:

```
<ion-list no-lines [virtualScroll]="ads | async">
        <button ion-item *virtualItem="let ad" (click)="onAdSelect(ad)" class="aero-item ">
            <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                <img src="assets/images/noimage.jpg" />
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <h2>{{ ad.model}}</h2>

        </button>
    </ion-list>
```

With this code, I´m getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at VirtualScroll._stepDOMWrite (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:92118:60)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:92078:23
    at dispatch (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20601:9)
    at DomController._flush (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20545:13)
    at rafCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20534:22)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure virtualScroll can work with async. Try to replace with ngFor and see the result

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found a workaround, although it's not optimal.

You see from [the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) `[virtualScroll]`expect an **Array**. While your `this.ads` return an **Observable**. That's why you got `Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

Workaround: Subscribe to it first then display on view (without async pipe), also keep in mind to unsubsribe when done.

```
ads: any[] = [];
constructor(public adProvider: AdProvider) {
    this.adProvider.getActiveAds().valueChanges().subscribe(results => this.ads = results);  
  }
```

Comment: I do as you say, but now, I get a different error: "Cannot read property 'dispose' of null

Comment: Maybe you can check out this test project of mine on this [link](https://github.com/vuhieptran95/myFirstIonicApp). Please pay attention to **speaker page** where I apply virtualscroll on an Observable. Hope this could help :)